# How to select from database using laravel where clause and created_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to select all the data on a database using laravel db query or Eloquent ORM. So i want all the data that are other than 3 days from the day they where created. Data 'A' is created on 15th i come in on 16th to check, i won't see Data 'A' but i may see others older than 3 days or equal to 3 days. If i come back on the 18th or 19th i should see Data 'A', obviously because it now older than 3 days or equal to.
so i wrote this code that is not working below

```
$users = DB::table('matched_users')->where( 'created_at', '>=',
 Carbon::now()->subDays(3));
```

so can anyone correct this for me.

when i did that it work but it shows both someone that his date is just one day one. so is that not enough code

```
Data Name - created_at
ozil        21/04/2012 16:09:22
mark        21/04/2012 16:09:22
cyril       22/04/2012 16:19:21
```

so today is 25/04/2012 if run the query of run the above query as it is i get all the result back.

But if change the `>=` to `<=` the result is an empty collection

Comment: @Snorehorse i just did

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean 'older than 3 days from the day they where created'. In this case the query should look like this:

```
DB::table('matched_users')->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::table('matched_users')->whereDate( 'created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get();
```

is the right way to write the code